# ¿Cómo recibir una variable de Livewire en un script de Javascript?

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewire

Mi componente livewire `app/Http/Livewire/Data.php`

```
class Data extends Component
{
    public $data= 0;

    public function data()
    {
        $this->data= 100;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.data');
    }
}
```

Mi vista livewire `resorces/views/livewire/data.blade.php` y deseo saber cómo puedo hacer uso de la variable `$data` dentro de un script que se encuentra en esta vista.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button wire:click="data"> Mi botón</button>
    <-- Aquí se muestra sin problemas -->
    <h1>{{ $data }}</h1>
</div>

<!-- Aquí no se muestra -->
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        let data = null;
        data = {{ $data }}
        console.log(data)    
    })
</script>
```

No me muestra el valor al hacer `console.log()`

Comment: El valor será fijo o necesitas que por ejemplo ante la interacción del usuario dando click la variable en JS tome el valor actualizado?

Comment: Hola @BetaM que el JS tome el valor actualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opción 1.**

Una forma es como la que recomienda la propia documentación, en la sección de [**Inline Scripts**](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts)

Del modo siguiente:

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', () => {

    let valorForaneo = @this.data;

});
```

**Sin embargo**, toma en cuenta el aviso que la propia documentación en el enlace provisto da y como bajo ciertas condiciones es preferible: *emitir eventos desde el componente y escucharlos vía js.*

**Opción 2.**

Por el contrario si necesitas que la variable actualice su valor dependiendo de la acción del usuario sobre la interfaz por ejemplo, entonces puedes proceder de esta forma:

Paso 1. En tu método `data` realiza un *emit* de esta manera:

```
   public function data()
   {
       $this->data= 100;
       $this->emit("valorData");
   }
```

Paso 2. Ahora dentro de tu componente en la vista escuchas dicho *emit* de esta forma:

```
   let data = null;

   document.addEventListener('livewire:load', () => {

       @this.on('valorData', () => {

           data = @this.data;

       })

   })
```

Donde lo que hicimos fue:

- Escuchar el evento emitido desde el componente en el backend, [*aqui puedes leer sobre dicha sintaxis en el aporte de Caleb*](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/356#issuecomment-552521704)
- A una variable previsamente declarada, le asignamos el valor de la propiedad `data`, (*si tienes dudas de este punto recomiendo leas el acceso a métodos y propiedades en el primer enlace que coloqué*)

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM como siempre de mucha ayuda tus respuestas... Aprendí un par de cosas que no entendía.

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo, es usando alpine y [@entangle](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#sharing-state) para vincular una variable de js con una de livewire. Este vínculo es bidireccional.

```
<div
    x-data="{ 
        js_data: @entangle('data') // vinculamos el la variable js con la de livewire - es completamente reactiva - la actualización funciona en ambas direcciones
    }"
>
    <div>Livewire data: {{$data}}</div>
    <div>JS data: <span x-text="js_data"></span></div>

    <button wire:click="data();">Update from Livewire</button>
    <button x-on:click="js_data = 25">Update from JS</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte!